# Remote desktop session is not working

Tags: remote-desktop

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. By doing a lots of searching in google, I noticed that many users are facing similar problem. As a solution of this problem, I have installed mate desktop according to suggestion of a blog. After that mate desktop session by xrdp is working only at first time. While I am trying to re-connect remote desktop session, it is not working again. How can I make remote desktop session persistent in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS?

Answer (score 0):

To have persistent connection (we assume that you want to reconnect to existing session),  you have two options

**upgrade your Ubuntu 14.04 to a higher version.**

The upgrade will allow you to use the new xrdp package (version 0.6-1.x) which allows you to reconnect to existing sessions (out of the box - no tweak necessary). You can see info [here](http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=6046)

**if you stick with ubuntu 14.04, you can**

- either perform a custom installation of xrdp (see instructions [here](http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=5439)) or
- get your hands on xrdp package available in ubuntu repository for 14.10. Ubuntu 14.10 released the xrdp package version 0.6-1.x which support out of the box reconnection to the same session

Hope this info is useful to other